# When I build docker-build it doesn't see the config file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The nginx.conf exists, but for some reason the docker does not see it, how to solve it?

```
FROM nginx
USER root
WORKDIR /D05/
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY ./server.c /home/server.c
COPY ./start.sh /home/start.sh
RUN apt-get update && apt install -y gcc libfcgi-dev spawn-fcgi;
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "./start.sh" ]

Step 4/8 : COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by
```

.dockerignore: stat nginx/nginx.conf: file does not exist

[image]
what could be causing the problem? Sorry for my English

Comment: You seem to have included a PNG-format image file in your question; Nginx can't read that as a configuration file.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including any relevant source code and outputs in plain text?

Answer (score 2):

Look to your terminal - it says that `COPY failed: file not found`.
Fix your `nginx.conf` path in `Dockerfile` on the line 4 (you don't have nginx folder)

```
...
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
...
```

After that I would recommend to check your `start.sh` if nginx is set correctly to start.